# How to get dimensions from string?

Tags: javascript

hi I'm a newbie at javascript and I'm trying to get dimensions from a string. This is the code:

```
var str = '1.jpeg (JPEG Image, 1298 × 1600 pixels)';
var index1 = str.indexOf('('), index2 = str.indexOf(')');
str = str.substr(index1+1, (index2-index1-1));
str = str.split('×');
alert(str);
```

I can't get it to output to `1298 × 1600` note the × isn't a regular x. Here's a live version http://jsfiddle.net/s5b4E/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a regular expression and String.match like this:

```
var str = '1.jpeg (JPEG Image, 1298 × 1600 pixels)';

var res = str.match(/[0-9]+\s[×]\s[0-9]+/);
```

If you don't understand how this expression works, just comment i gonna give detailed information.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Z3Z6/)

Answer (score 0):

This would be an easy task with the use of Regex. Something like this will work:

```
var str = '1.jpeg (JPEG Image, 1298 × 1600 pixels)';
var regex = /\d+ × \d+/;
var result = str.match(regex)[0];
```

Explanation: `\d+` will match any number and  `×`  will match the middle part. Combining these together will match the result you are looking for.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/s5b4E/1/)

---

**NOTE**: This regex makes a couple of assumptions about the formatting, the biggest one being that the whitespace is always present around the result, and the whitespace around the `×` is always one each side. If the format might change then let me know as the regex can be adapted. The code also assumes that a match will be guaranteed, but I think this is fair as your format looks fairly reliable - of course, only you will know which assumptions are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "1.jpeg (JPEG Image, 1298 × 1600 pixels)";
var res = str.split(" ")[3] + "x" + str.split(" ")[5];
```

That would give you the resolution as as string with a real "x". You can also use the x and y resolution directly as integer, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

A regex would seem to be a good way to go. Here I use `match` to return an array of matched elements:

```
var regex = /\s(\d+)\s×\s(\d+)\s/
var matches = str.match(regex); // matches[1] = 1298, matches[2] = 1600
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/za4Dk/1/)